# Identify image file from table in MS Word

Tags: python, python-docx

I read an MS-Word file using docx python library. The word file contains tables (only 1 column in tables) like table1, table2 and so on. I need to read it table by table. Whenever a row has one or more picture file  i need to display "image file found" in table# and row#"

Here is what i have done. The **inline_shapes property** from docx api gives the list of objects for image files found.But it does not specify the table number and row number where it found the image.

```
from docx.api import Document

doc = Document("demo.docx")

for image in doc.inline_shapes:
    print(image)

for table in doc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            print(cell.text) # it prints only the text and no info about image
```

Few helpful references

[python docx how to read text along with inline images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231408/python-docx-how-to-read-text-along-with-inline-images)

[Finding image present docx file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691678/finding-image-present-docx-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

`python-docx` doesn't yet support this scenario very well but here's one way to approach it:

```
from docx.api import Document

doc = Document("demo.docx")

for table_index, table in enumerate(doc.tables):
    for row_index, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for cell_index, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            blips = cell._element.xpath('*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/a:blip')
            if type(blips) is list:
                for blip in blips:
                    # sample output:
                    # table[12] row[2] cell[0] link_to_image[rId17]
                    print('table[{}] row[{}] cell[{}] link_to_image[{}]'
                          .format(table_index, row_index, cell_index, blip.embed))

                    # write to file
                    image_part = doc.part.related_parts[blip.embed]
                    with open('demo.png', 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(image_part.blob)
```

Not ideal, but does the trick.